# Module sockjs-client has no exported member "SockJS"

Tags: typescript, aurelia, sockjs

I am trying to import SockJS from the sockjs-client library. I am using Aurelia and typescript, but when trying to import that with

```
import { SockJS } from 'sockjs-client';
```

it says in VS2015: "Module sockjs-client has no exported member "SockJS""

package.json looks like this:

```
 "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
     //......
  "sockjs": "npm:sockjs@^0.3.17",
  "sockjs-client": "npm:sockjs-client@^1.1.1",
  "stompjs": "npm:stompjs@^2.3.3",
},
"devDependencies": {}
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
import SockJS = require('sockjs-client');
```

Comment: this doesn't add typings though.

Answer (score 4):

Try to install sockjs-client typings `npm install --save @types/sockjs-client` and then import `import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';`

Answer (score 1):

this alone should do the trick:    `npm install --save-dev @types/sockjs-client` 
no need for the import as. It comes from TS